# How to train with a dataset of images where the labels are also images?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on building a neural network for super resolution. I have a dataset consisting of 2 folders, each containing 100990 pictures. The first folder has the images in resolution 128x128x3 and the second folder has the images in resolution of 32x32x3. As input, I want to give the neural network the 32x32x3 images. Then as output, I want to give the neural network the 128x128x3 images. Ideally, the neural network will learn how to map the 32x32x3 images to the 128x128x3 images to perform super resolution.

I worked on an autoencoder project previously which also used images as the input and output to the NN. But it was on a much smaller dataset containing only 800 pictures. The way I did that was to load all the images as an array into RAM using code like this:

```
from PIL import ImageOps, Image
size = 64, 64

for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir, "pokemon_jpg")):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(base_dir, "pokemon_jpg", f)).resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    break

big_arr = np.array([np.array(im)]).reshape(1, 64, 64, 3)
for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(base_dir,"pokemon_jpg"))[1:]:
    big_arr = np.append(big_arr, [np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(base_dir, "pokemon_jpg", f)).resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)).reshape(64, 64, 3)], axis=0)
    #i+=1
    
big_arr = big_arr/255
```

But, since my current dataset consists of 100,000+ images, I can't just load them all into RAM at the same time. In order to train the model, I would need to load batches of images at a time. I've tried using tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory() but when I make an image_dataset_from_directory it uses the name of the folder as the label (as it should). But how would I make a similar image_dataset_from_directory but have the labels be the 128x128x3 images so that I can feed it into the neural network?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
# building the neural network with input shape (None, 32, 32, 3) and output shape (None, 128, 128, 3)
input_img = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
model = keras.Model(input_img, x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy')

resized_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir, "resized_food_high_res_images")
converted_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir, "train_food_images_low_res" )

labels_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(resized_dir, label_mode=None, image_size=(128, 128), shuffle=False)
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(converted_dir,label_mode = None, image_size=(32, 32), shuffle=False)

model.fit(labels_dataset, train_dataset,
         epochs=3,
         batch_size=128)
```

The model summary is:

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 32, 32, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 8)         224       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 8)         584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_8 (UpSampling2 (None, 64, 64, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 16)        1168      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_9 (UpSampling2 (None, 128, 128, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 3)       435       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,731
Trainable params: 4,731
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

It is to my understanding that I'm receiving this error because the image_dataset_from_directory has the label of the folder name for the pictures. But I can't find any information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator that you are passing to the fit sequence must generate a tuple `(img1, img2)`. You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.zip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) to achieve the desired shape :

```
labels_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(resized_dir, label_mode=None, image_size=(128, 128), shuffle=False)
train_dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(converted_dir,label_mode = None, image_size=(32, 32), shuffle=False)
# zipping
zipped_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_dataset, labels_dataset))
```

And then you can call `fit`:

```
model.fit(zipped_ds)
```

Comment: When running that code, I received an error " ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), found shape=(None, None, 32, 32, 3)".

Then I tried changing the input layer of the model to be "input_img = tf.keras.Input(batch_input_shape=(32, 32, 32, 3))" but I received the same error. 

But then when I removed the .batch(32) from the zipped_ds, it worked!

Comment: Ah, it's possible that `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` is already doing the batching. I'll edit my answer.